Is my derailleur pulley just out of positioned or bent/broken? Just purchased my first bike
I recently purchase my first bike Univega Weekend Escape 1.0 which arrived today. I am new to bicycle but i was able to guide myself using Youtube video and assembled it.
When i finished putting things together, i noticed this 'derailleuer pulley' and how it seems to be out of position when compared to the cassette. I set the gear to the lowest and checked again but it seems completely off to me Video 1 and Video 2.
Could someone please confirm if this is broken or needs an alignment/service? I would love a confirmation so i can request a replacement or take it to a service instead of return/refund. Unfortunately, a bike shop is so far away from me so i am hoping an expert online could confirm.

P.S. The package/box was badly damaged and there were already few issues with the bike so i am really unsure at this time (Front wheel slightly bent, one thread/screw to bar handle seems damaged, all reflectors came broken, minor noticable scratches).
Update #1: After I pedaled (not riding the bike), the chain/derailleur  adjusted itself :D


It is not a good angle photograph to assess anything. Please make a picture directly from behind, as straight as possible with the sected cog.

From the video it looks like the gears were shifted without pedaling.  The chain needs to be moving as the derailer is shifted between gears.  From those positions, if you pedal what happens (lift the rear wheel so is spins and turn pedals, don't ride the bike)
Have a look at Parktool repair  help - https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment

@mattnz Hi Matt, thank you for your response. I pedaled the bike in the manner you mentioned and the chain + derailer adjusted on its own. I will also check the blog and attempt to adjust later today.

@VladimirFГероямслава Hi Vladimir, I uploaded a new picture :D (i also compiled more in this link here as well https://imgur.com/a/nrRZ9q0

It looks bend inwards to me, but some derailleurs do and lenses do funny things at close range
